# How select 1 element in listing of custom-control-input items

Tags: vuejs2, custom-controls

In  @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuejs app I have listing of items and I have with custom checkbox
to select only 1 item. I do like

```
    <tr v-for="nextUsersAssignedToTask in usersAssignedToTask" :key="nextUsersAssignedToTask.id" >

        <td class="text-center">
            <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    :name="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    :id="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    :value="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    v-model="selected_users_assigned_to_task_id"
            >
```

But when I select/deselect 1 item 
1) my selected_users_assigned_to_task_id var has value true/false, but I expected got value nextUsersAssignedToTask.id
2) all elements are selected/deselected, not 1 as I need
Which is valid way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <tr v-for="nextUsersAssignedToTask in usersAssignedToTask" :key="nextUsersAssignedToTask.id" >
            <td class="text-center">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    :name="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    :id="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    :value="'custom_selected_users_assigned_to_task_id_'+nextUsersAssignedToTask.id"
                    v-model="nextUsersAssignedToTask.selected"
                    v-on:change="changeItem(nextUsersAssignedToTask)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                usersAssignedToTask: [
                    {id: 1, text: '1', selected: false},
                    {id: 2, text: '2', selected: false},
                ]
            };
        }
        methods: {
            changeItem(item) {
                console.log('item ' + item.id + ' changed to ' + item.selected);
            }
        },
        watch: {
            'usersAssignedToTask': {
                handler: function() {
                    console.log(this.usersAssignedToTask)
                },
                deep: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! With your code applied I can select/deselection any checkbox, but how can I do only 1 element selectable(last checked) ?

Comment: @PeterSmith , i edit code and add v-on:change on input element for your purpose. also add a method for log any change.

Comment: Thanks, with changeItem method I can get id of last clicked item, but as I have several items clicked in listing I need to 
deselect all priorly clicked items. How can I do this ?

Comment: @PeterSmith add a button or an input (checkbox) above this exist element and on change event's, false all selected of usersAssignedToTask.

Comment: @PeterSmith or you can add this to template section : `<tr>
 <input
  type="checkbox"
  class="custom-control-input"
  v-model="general_checkbox">
</tr>` and this code add to watch: `general_checkbox() {
 this.usersAssignedToTask.forEach(item => {
  item.selected = this.general_checkbox;
 })
}` and add variable general_checkbox to data

Comment: I tried with general_checkbox, but failed. Please, take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b5orqn8g/

Comment: @PeterSmith Hi. i edit your jsfiddle and save this https://jsfiddle.net/mahdad40/36r4zf9n/2/

Comment: Thanks!, but it is a bit different I need : i user clicks 1 element, all the rest must be deselected. Now 2 elements can be selected!